# Plotting many tables in a single plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have several lists.

```
HeapSort = {6046.315617631054, 10120.421973039713, 20443.896966227818, 39888.26738991704, 409953.65081967216, 822796.7730263158, 1668210.1566666667, 3417061.523809524, 7231431.842857143, 1.58387906875*10^7, 3.3356646333333332*10^7, 6.99283795*10^7};
InsertSort = {1271.5641210832696, 2687.027971840069, 7428.082168377579, 26163.114593689497, 3480848.111111111, 1.7492152862068966*10^7, 7.876655514285715*10^7, 4.397160115*10^8, 2.19177605*10^9, 9.608922293*10^9, 4.5711371557*10^10,  2.88336011071*10^11};
MergeSort = {705.8025660136586, 757.6872519529326, 712.2989003537274, 712.1736108341547, 1059.3028590671972, 1497.1111723262381, 2410.7281094659293, 4422.600003538069, 10639.153797050876, 21691.320766994926, 45971.68456375839, 91827.67235996327};
QuickSort = {780.2510673824163, 899.0357995655863, 1229.733878841987, 2115.2551030336876, 46303.74590239837, 115050.7630004602, 271829.77228260867, 603560.328106152, 1342529.6916890081, 2965269.349112426, 6622509.02631579, 1.5045565676470589*10^7};
SelectionSort = {1626.7971290340422, 5189.992121652481, 17446.351430565246, 63880.23454266735, 6390999.493670886, 2.6850240684210528*10^7, 1.068697138*10^8, 4.399030115*10^8, 1.784892424*10^9, 7.214766123*10^9, 3.0060269881*10^10,  1.35096492432*10^11};
Num = {10, 25, 50, 100, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 32000, 64000, 128000};
```

They are tests I have performed with different sorting algorithms.

I have the following code to put all of them in a single plot.

```
ListLinePlot[
 {
  Table[{Num[[i]], HeapSort[[i]]}, {i, 12}],
  Table[{Num[[i]], InsertSort[[i]]}, {i, 12}], 
  Table[{Num[[i]], MergeSort[[i]]}, {i, 12}],
  Table[{Num[[i]], QuickSort[[i]]}, {i, 12}], 
  Table[{Num[[i]], SelectionSort[[i]]}, {i, 12}]
  },
 PlotLegend -> {"Heap Sort", "Insertion Sort", "Merge Sort", 
   "Quick Sort", "Selection Sort"}, LegendPosition -> {1, -0.25},
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 PlotLabel -> "Average Time of Heap Sort",
  AxesLabel -> {"Test Number", "Nano Seconds"},
 ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

For some reason, I can't get the plots to show up correctly. The x axis only goes up to around 80000. This is fixed when I remove all but one of the Table lists in the above code.

If you guys could help me debug this code and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Have you tried restarting the kernel and starting from scratch with this code?

Comment: Does `PlotRange -> All` option to `ListLinePlot` help?

Comment: The `PlotRange->All` did help. I actually think I am going to be using the below answer. The graph will turn out much nicer I think. Also, the restart worked out great. I think something got caught up or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try:

```
ListLogPlot[Transpose /@ Reverse /@ 
   Partition[
    Riffle[{HeapSort, InsertSort, MergeSort, QuickSort, SelectionSort}, {Num}, {2, -1, 2}], 2],
   PlotRange -> Full, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This graph looks great. Thanks! Just one thing though.. What happened to selection sort? There is only 4 lines on there when there should be 5.

Edit: I added `{}` as a final list, so that it shows all 5 real ones. But what really went on here? Since this probably isn't proper behavior.

Comment: @MiloGertjejansen Sorry, I made a mistake with the Riffle functions. Corrected now.

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
dat = {Num, #}\[Transpose] & /@
 {HeapSort, InsertSort, MergeSort, QuickSort, SelectionSort};

ListLogLogPlot[dat,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 PlotLabel -> "Average Time of Heap Sort",
 AxesLabel -> {"Test Number", "Nano Seconds"},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 Joined -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The plot title seems misleading

Comment: @belisarius No argument here.  It's what the OP had in his so I left it.

Comment: Hey! I haven't see it! sorry

Comment: Yeah, changed it in my work last night.. It should be Average Time of Sorts.

Comment: @Milo image changed accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you may plot them first.  If you don't want to see them, simply add `;` after the code.  After plotting them all, use `Show[a1,a2,……,an]`.  That's all.

With code:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{Num[[i]], #[[i]]}, {i, 12}], 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "Average Time of Heap Sort", 
  AxesLabel -> {"Test Number", "Nano Seconds"}, ImageSize -> Large] & /@
 {HeapSort, InsertSort, MergeSort, QuickSort, SelectionSort};

Show[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm not sure that this answer addresses any aspect of the OP's question, though?

Comment: Ok,+1 _after_ @Mr.Wizard's edit.